# Javascript - Catch does catch error when thrown

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

So im trying to catch an exception when the server responds with an undefined ID variable but i think asynchronicity is getting in the way. Any tips on how to make it work?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNRmz.jpg - not enough rep for pictures ..

Comment: add code to the question, image of code is tiresome

Comment: Read this to learn [how to use code block](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/5r143L6.png

Answer (score 1):

`try`/`catch` is active in the context in which a function runs, not the context in which function is defined. What you've done is define functions with to an array; there was no exception in doing that. What happens, later when the functions run? With regard to the defined `try`/`catch`, nothing (since the functions are running somewhere else).

That has nothing to do with whether the functions are running asynchronously or not, but running them asynchronously allows you to run them outside the `try`/`catch` context more easily.

Next time, submit your question with the sample, inline, in text form and minimized to show the essence your problem, along with the essential parts which invoke your problem code.